# on screen keyboard hiding EditText in landscape Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-softkeyboard

I have tried changing `softInputeMode` property to `AdjustResize` and `AdjustPan` and nothing works

**Class with SoftInputMode attribute:**

```
[Activity(Label = "TextActivity", Theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Transparent.NoActionBar", 
        MainLauncher =true,ScreenOrientation =Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.FullSensor,
        WindowSoftInputMode =SoftInput.AdjustResize & SoftInput.AdjustPan)]
    public class TextActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.textsearch_layout);
            // Create your application here
        }
    }
```

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00000000">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:src="@drawable/local_icon">
                </ImageButton>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:src="@drawable/cloud_icon">
                </ImageButton>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:src="@drawable/beta_icon">
                </ImageButton>
            </LinearLayout>
         <com.libizo.CustomEditText

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:hint="Test"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/opensans_light"
            app:libIZO_setBackgroundColor="#992980B9"
            app:libIZO_setPrefixTextColor="#ffffff"
            app:libIZO_clearIconTint="#ffffff"
            app:libIZO_setBorderColor="#E1E0E1"
            app:libIZO_setBorderView="true"
            app:libIZO_setClearIconVisible="true"
            app:libIZO_setCornerRadius="18dp"
            app:libIZO_setStrokeWidth="2dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you get the solution for this am also facing same problem in landscape mode

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can replace WindowSoftInputMode =SoftInput.AdjustResize & SoftInput.AdjustPan by **WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.StateHidden| SoftInput.AdjustResize**, and putting a layer of **scrollview** on the outermost UI.

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true, ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.FullSensor, WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.StateHidden| SoftInput.AdjustResize )]


<ScrollView  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:src="@drawable/check">
            </ImageButton>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:src="@drawable/uncheck">
            </ImageButton>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:src="@drawable/icaon">
            </ImageButton>
        </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text = "11111111"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text = "11111111"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text = "11111111"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text = "11111111"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text = "11111111"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text = "11111111"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text = "11111111"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text = "11111111"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text = "11111111"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text = "11111111"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text = "11111111"/>
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:imeOptions="actionGo"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

Comment: I Provide some code and gif here, you can see that on screen keyboard don't hide EditText, if you still have this issue, please remember to post your entire, I will try to reproduce your issue.